# Motrar valor de file_get_contents mas somente o que esta entre aspas

Tags: php

Segue código:

```
<?
    $url="url_aqui";
    $result = file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

A variável `$result` retorna o valor exatamente dessa forma: `document.write('11,90');`

Eu preciso pegar somente o valor que esta entre as aspas, no caso: **11,90**

Qual condição poderia usar para fazer isso?

Código atualizado:

```
$valor_mensal="url_monthly";
$valor_trimestral="url_quarterly";
$valor_semestral="url_semiannually";
$valor_anual="url_annually";

$b_mensal = file_get_contents($valor_mensal);
$b_trimestral = file_get_contents($valor_trimestral);
$b_semestral = file_get_contents($valor_semestral);
$b_anual = file_get_contents($valor_anual);

$primeiroCaractere_b_mensal = strpos($b_mensal, "'");
$primeiroCaractere_b_trimestral = strpos($b_trimestral, "'");
$primeiroCaractere_b_semestral = strpos($b_semestral, "'");
$primeiroCaractere_b_anual = strpos($b_anual, "'");

$basico_mensal = substr($b_mensal, $primeiroCaractere_b_mensal+1, -3);
$basico_trimestral = substr($b_trimestral, $primeiroCaractere_b_trimestral+1, -3);
$basico_semestral = substr($b_semestral, $primeiroCaractere_b_semestral+1, -3);
$basico_anual = substr($b_anual, $primeiroCaractere_b_anual+1, -3);
```

A URL é composta dessa forma:

https://dominio.com/feeds/productsinfo.php?pid=3&get=price&billingcycle=monthly
https://dominio.com/feeds/productsinfo.php?pid=3&get=price&billingcycle=quarterly
https://dominio.com/feeds/productsinfo.php?pid=3&get=price&billingcycle=semiannually
https://dominio.com/feeds/productsinfo.php?pid=3&get=price&billingcycle=annually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Misture [substr](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php) e [strpos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php). Fica mais ou menos assim:

```
<?

$valor_mensal=processaValor("https://dominio.com/feeds/productsinfo.php?pid=3&get=price&billingcycle=monthly");
$valor_trimestral=processaValor("https://dominio.com/feeds/productsinfo.php?pid=3&get=price&billingcycle=quarterly");
$valor_semestral=processaValor("https://dominio.com/feeds/productsinfo.php?pid=3&get=price&billingcycle=semiannually");
$valor_anual=processaValor("https://dominio.com/feeds/productsinfo.php?pid=3&get=price&billingcycle=annually");

function processaValor($url) {
    $result = file_get_contents($url);
    $primeiroCaractere = strpos($result, "'");
    $valor = substr($result, $primeiroCaractere+1, -3);
    return valor;
}

?>
```

Valor receberá a atribuição desejada.

Comment: E se o valor for 111,90 ou então 1.111,90? Nem sempre será o mesmo valor ali.

Comment: O último parâmetro, quando negativo, sempre vai contar do fim da string. Então ele remove os três últimos caracteres, que serão sempre os mesmos `');`

Comment: Muito bom, funcionou.. Mas ficou um código muito extenso, você pode me ajudar a simplificar o código se possível? Pois são vários planos que vou precisar fazer. Eu atualizei a pergunta com o código atualizado.

Comment: Você pode criar uma função que vai te retornar esse valor. Vou atualizar a resposta

Comment: Muito obrigado. Acrescentei mais detalhes, de como é a URL.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar `preg_match` para pegar o valor numérico entre as aspas:

```
$result = "document.write('11,90');";
preg_match('/(\.?\d,?)+/', $result, $match);
echo $match[0]; // imprime 11,90
```

**[Teste no RegExr](https://regexr.com/3qt6c)**

Explicação da regex:

```
()   -> captura o grupo
\.?  -> verifica se existe um ponto e captura também o que tiver antes de número (backreference)
\d   -> captura números
,?   -> verifica se há uma vírgula e captura números após
+    -> junta o que foi encontrado
```