# Mudar valores de acordo com a opção selecionada

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Estou com uma tabela de planos aqui, e nela possuí 5 colunas, para 5 planos obviamente.

Em cada coluna existe um select para escolher a periodicidade de cada plano.

De acordo com a opção selecionada nesse select, ele deve alterar o valor que esta sendo exibido para o plano.

Eu tentei iniciar um script mas não consegui fazer com que ele trabalhe como preciso.

Vou deixar o código completo abaixo:

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script>
$(function() {
  // PLANO BÁSICO US
  // preciso usar o str_replace por que o valor é obtido através de uma variável PHP
  var plano_basicoUS = {
    1: <? echo str_replace(',', '.', 11,90); ?>,
    2: <? echo str_replace(',', '.', 32,70); ?>,
    3: <? echo str_replace(',', '.', 59,40); ?>,
    4: <? echo str_replace(',', '.', 106,80); ?>,
 };


  $("#periodicidadeBasicoUS").on('change', function() {

    var periodo = this;
    var escolha = $(this).val();
    var multiplicar = $(this).find(':selected').data('multiplicar');

    $.each($('.periodo-item'), function(key, value) {
      var plano = $(value).data('plano');
      var preco = plano_basicoUS[1] * multiplicar;

      $(value).find('.valor_original').text('R$ '+preco);
      $(value).find('.valor_desconto').text('R$ '+plano_basicoUS[2]);
      $(value).find('.valor_mensal').text(plano_basicoUS[1]);

    });

  });

  $("#periodicidadeBasicoUS").trigger('change');


});
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<br>
<div class="periodo-item" data-plano="1">
    <span class="valor_original"></span> <span class="valor_desconto"></span>
    <br>
    <span class="valor_mensal"></span>
</div>

    <div class="select">
        <select name="periodicidadeBasicoUS" id="periodicidadeBasicoUS">
          <option value="1">Mensal - Sem desconto</option>
          <option data-multiplicar="3" value="2">Trimestral - </option>
          <option data-multiplicar="6" value="3">Semestral - </option>
          <option data-multiplicar="12" value="4">Anual - </option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

Eu preciso que ele faça o seguinte:

1. Retorne os valores com virgula em vez de ponto, ex: R$ 11,90.
2. Se selecionado a opção com value 1 (mensal) ele deve mostrar um texto qualquer nos `span` com classes: **valor_original** e **valor_desconto** e para a classe **valor_mensal** seria o valor de `plano_basicoUS[1]`, para as outras opções serão apresentados os valores numéricos normais.

Como devo ajustar o script?

Como são vários planos, se alguém souber como simplificar esse código seria interessante, pois vou precisar repetir todo o código para o próximo plano.

Comment: Note que você não está salvando os dados que você tá puxando do PHP em um array, mas sim em um objeto javascript. Por isso que provavelmente não tá imprimindo quando você usa `plano_basicoUS[1]`

Comment: Ele ta imprimindo, só que ta mostrando com ponto e sem o zero no final.

Comment: Sim, percebi só depois que você tava com os indicies do objeto corretos... O tipo de dado que tá entrando no str_replace é realmente uma string? Note que sem as aspas, você tá passando um número. Além disso, a ordem dos parametros está trocada. Deveria ser `echo str_replace('.', ',', "11.90");` https://ideone.com/JqB4FD

Comment: Então, é que no PHP ele retorna o valor com virgula, ai como o JS não faz a multiplicação com virgula precisei usar o str_replace para converter com ponto. `$basicoUS_mensal > 11,90`

Comment: Eu entendo. Agora vamos lá. Você recebe a string do PHP já formatada e quer fazer a operação? Você teria que usar parseFloat nesse caso. Você não pode multiplicar uma string por um número por exemplo. Ficaria mais ou menos assim: `parseFloat(<?echo str_replace(',', '.', "11,90");?>)`. Isso aí vai te voltar o número real `11.9` no JS e vai te permitir realizar operações com ele. Depois, para imprimir você precisaria formatar para o jeito que você quer que o valor final seja impresso.

Comment: Sim, eu recebo a string já formatada com virgula. Acho que foi você que me ajudou na outra questão né? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/306283/motrar-valor-de-file-get-contents-mas-somente-o-que-esta-entre-aspas/306309#306309

Comment: Certo, eu te sugeriria, se possível, fazer a alteração da vírgula pra ponto, se possível, já no arquivo em PHP que volta esses dados pra tu, e no javascript só usar `parseFloat()` pra poder fazer operações matemáticas usando esse valor e depois formatar pra poder imprimir como você quiser.

Comment: E como posso formatar o valor que é impresso pelo js?

Comment: Aí teria que criar uma função que formate esse número. Exemplo: https://ideone.com/vEFRoQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use um ternário para mostrar apenas texto nas primeiras `div`s quando o valor do `select` não for `1`.

O ternário tem esta estrutura:

```
condição ? valor se for verdadeira : valor se for falsa
```

Aplicaria aqui:

```
$(value)
.find('.valor_original')
.text(escolha != 1 ? 'R$ '+preco.toFixed(2).replace(".",",") : '');
            ↑                      ↑                           ↑
//      condição          se for verdadeira,             se for falsa,
//                     insere o texto com o valor           esvazia
```

Para formatar os valores, você usa `.toFixed(2).replace(".",",")` (2 casas decimais e substitui o ponto pela vírgula).

**Veja:**

```js
$(function() {
  // PLANO BÁSICO US
  // preciso usar o str_replace por que o valor é obtido através de uma variável PHP
  var plano_basicoUS = {
    1: 11.90,
    2: 32.70,
    3: 59.40,
    4: 106.80,
 };


  $("#periodicidadeBasicoUS").on('change', function() {

    var periodo = this;
    var escolha = $(this).val();
    var multiplicar = $(this).find(':selected').data('multiplicar');

    $.each($('.periodo-item'), function(key, value) {
      var plano = $(value).data('plano');
      var preco = plano_basicoUS[1] * multiplicar;
      
      $(value).find('.valor_original').text(escolha != 1 ? 'R$ '+preco.toFixed(2).replace(".",",") : ''); // ternário
      $(value).find('.valor_desconto').text(escolha != 1 ? 'R$ '+plano_basicoUS[2].toFixed(2).replace(".",",") : '');  // ternário
      $(value).find('.valor_mensal').text(plano_basicoUS[1].toFixed(2).replace(".",","));

    });

  });

  $("#periodicidadeBasicoUS").trigger('change');


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="periodo-item" data-plano="1">
    <span class="valor_original"></span> <span class="valor_desconto"></span>
    <br>
    <span class="valor_mensal"></span>
</div>

<div class="select">
  <select name="periodicidadeBasicoUS" id="periodicidadeBasicoUS">
    <option value="1">Mensal - Sem desconto</option>
    <option data-multiplicar="3" value="2">Trimestral - </option>
    <option data-multiplicar="6" value="3">Semestral - </option>
    <option data-multiplicar="12" value="4">Anual - </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito bom mesmo, mas fiquei em dúvida no seguinte: O primeiro valor de `valor_original` aparece corretamente pois ele deve apenas multiplicar o valor de `plano_basicoUS[1`], porém o `valor_desconto` não esta sendo alterado de acordo com a opção selecionada. Cada opção possuí um valor diferente. A outra dúvida é como faço para alterar o texto que é exibido quando é selecionado a opção 1?

Comment: Perfeito, consegui resolver. Esqueci de um detalhe, eu preciso que no valor_mensal, ele exiba o valor de uma divisão, tentei fazer o seguinte: `var equivalente = preco / multiplicar;` `$(value).find('.valor_mensal').text(escolha != 1 ? equivalente.toFixed(2).replace(".",",") : plano_basicoUS[escolha].toFixed(2).replace(".",","));`. O que fiz de errado? Não funcionou.

Comment: Consegui ajustar!

Comment: Mais uma dúvida, é possível colocar um `<strike></strike>` no valor impresso em valor_desconto? Tentei aqui e não consegui aplicar essa propriedade css. Ou poderia ser o text-decoration:line-through em vez do strike.

Comment: Corrigindo, seria para o valor impresso em: valor_original, sendo somente para o valor numérico.

Comment: Sim, já ta dessa forma, o problema é que quando é selecionado a primeira opção ele vai exibir o texto, e no texto não pode estar riscado.

Comment: Não, vc coloca isso no JS: `$(value).find('.valor_original').text(escolha != 1 ? 'R$ '+preco.toFixed(2).replace(".",",") : '<span class="strike">texto aqui</span>'); // ternário`

Comment: Então, teria que ser ao contrário, o texto naõ pode ser riscado, preciso que apenas o valor numérico esteja riscado. Posso colocar a primeira parte dentro das aspas tbm?

Comment: Desculpe a minha falta de conhecimento, tentei o seguinte mas não funcionou: `$(value).find('.valor_original').text(escolha != 1 ? '<span class="strike">R$ '+preco.toFixed(2).replace(".",",")'</span>' : 'Altere a');`

Comment: Faltou o `+` pra concatenar: `$(value).find('.valor_original').text(escolha != 1 ? '<span class="strike">R$ '+preco.toFixed(2).replace(".",",")+'</span>' : 'Altere a');`

Comment: Tinha tentando também, mas ele imprimiu o span, não entendeu como html.

Comment: Imprimiu exatamente dessa forma: <span class="strike">R$ 35,70</span> R$ 32,70

Comment: ah tah.. esqueci... troca o text por html

Comment: Eitaa, agora sim, 100%! Uma última dúvida, última mesmo kk, teria alguma forma de simplificar o código para não precisar repetir todo o código para cada plano? Por que no exemplo o   `var plano_basicoUS =` refere-se ao primeiro plano, e existem mais de 10, que serão com outros nomes, ex:   `var plano_proUS = `

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78808/discussion-between-dvd-and-wendler).

Comment: pode me ajudar a ajustar o replace para ele colocar o ponto em milhar, ex: 1.000,00